# Resize iFrame if screen width is less than x

Tags: html, iframe

I have an iFrame that displays an advertisement 990x90.

I want to make it so mobile viewers can still see the ad, but I need the iframe to resize "evenly", for example, if screen width is 900 I need the hight to be proportionate.

Please help :)

Comment: Providing code with your question, or a http://jsfiddle.net would be so helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'd of been so practical if you wrote the code you tried to do what you are asked for so that guys on here can help you as it is hard to guess what your code/goal is or to build it from scratch, *However* for this time, here is the code you need to achieve what you are asking for as you can see it in action in this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dyx9wx2p/), and here's the code needed:

**JS:**

```
iFrameOriginalWidth = $('iframe').width();
OnResize();
$(window).resize(function() {
    OnResize();
});

function OnResize(){
    var winWidth = $(window).width();
    if(winWidth < 900){
        $('iframe').css({'max-width':'100%'});
    }else{
        $('iframe').css({'max-width':iFrameOriginalWidth}); 
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<h2>Welcome to my iFrame</h2>
<iframe src="http://www.coffeeipsum.com" width="1100" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" />
```